# Visual Studio Wcf Test Client - entering an Int array

Tags: visual-studio, wcf, wcftestclient

I've found the Visual Studio WCF test client quite useful when it comes to a quick test of my WCF service.
This is the test client found in this location relative to your Visual Studio install directory:

> \Common7\IDE\WcfTestClient.exe

I have a few service calls that require a parameter of type System.Int32[]
I can't seem to figure out what values to enter against for this parameter as i keep receiving the error

> '[value entered]' is not a valid value for this type

Trying to enter the value 27 i have tried the following, but all fails

> 27
>   { 27 }
>   new System.Int32[] { 27 }

Can anyone please help with how to do this

Answer (score 248, accepted):

Type `length=1` in the `Value` column, a `▶` will appear allowing you to add values in the array:

[image: WCF Test Client Preview]

Comment: In my case, it was not exaclty a `+`. It was more of a `▶`.

Comment: Ah, yes, that is what I should expect when initialising a new array!